# Excel VBA Copy and Paste loop accounting for blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to using VBA. I have an Excel document that has 500 sheets worth of data each sheet only has at most 45 rows and up to column W. I am trying to have a macro that copies the data from each of the 500 sheets and pastes it into a sheet named "Master". I am able to use the following code to perform this successfully.

```
Sub CopyPaste() 

    Dim wks As Worksheet 

       For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       If Not wks.Name = "Master" Then
       wks.Range("A1:W" & wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
       Destination:=Worksheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    End If
    Next 

End Sub
```

The issue I am running into is that some of the sheets have a row that is blank below the header before the data begins and as my code is written currently it seems like the macro thinks this is the end of the page and moves to the next sheet and is missing data that should be copied and pasted. I am looking for some assistance/guidance on how to account for these blank cells/rows so that the copy and pasting continue for the sheet through the end. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Try to use UsedRange to count the number of rows in every sheet like that: Worksheets(yourworkingsheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count.

Comment: *"currently the macro assumes this is the end of the page and moves to the next sheet"*. I don't see that ability in the code you provided above. Is this just a snippet of code?

Comment: @Toddleson as I mentioned above I am new to VBA so I mis-spoke. I assume that this is what is happening as the macro is working as I needed except for that issue.

Comment: @Mohamad Thank you so much, I will try this out and see if I can make it work. I appreciate it.

Comment: One thing to look out for using your approach is that if you have empty cells in column 'A' (in the bottom rows of the data), you will be pasting over data in the other columns. 
Making better use of 'UsedRange' should limit that issue.